# XPath to element with changing id?

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath, xpath-2.0

I am trying to locate one element using Selenium with XPath.
When I inspect the same element and copy the XPath, it is

```
//*[@id="Body react-aria-**16**"]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/div
```

However, the number "**16**" may change every time I load the page.
How can I reliably locate this element using `find_element(By.XPATH, XPath)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To eliminate dependence on the trailing number, use `starts-with()`:

```
//*[starts-with(@id,"Body react-aria-")]
```

Append whatever invariant suffix is needed from there.